# Angular - @HostBinding() - Can read classes added from HTML

Tags: angular

I need to add dynamically class from typescript to component and preserve classes which programmer added from HTML template. But if I use @HostBinding('class') classes: string => all classes added from outside will be ignored.

```
<my-component class"thisWillBeIgnored"></my-component>
```

Do I need to read classes from outside first and add to them my class from typescript? HOW? :D

Thank you

Comment: use `@HostBinding('class.<class-name>')`, instead of  `@HostBinding('class')`

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution for you is to use the ngClass directive to apply the classes to your component. Then inside your component, you should use the renderer's addClass method to add any new classes.

```
<my-component [ngClass]="'my-custom-class'"></my-component>
```

In MyComponent:

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private eltRef: ElementRef) {
}

ngOnInit () {
  this.renderer.addClass(this.eltRef.nativeElement, 'my-other-custom-class');
}
```

Of course you don't need to add the classes specifically in the ngOnInit method, it's just an example.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is not a better solution than @Fredriks_Macrobond one but easiest way was:

```
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
  }

  @Input()
  set size(value: number) {
    if (condition) {
      this.el.nativeElement.classList.add(this.desiredClass);
    }
  }
```